# Openlayers shows and paints polygons in the wrong place on the map

Tags: geoserver, javascript, openlayers

In the following code I call a geoserver service.

Initialize map

```
var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.OSM()
            })
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.transform([0,0],'EPSG:4326','EPSG:3857'),
          zoom: 2
    })
    });
```

Then I make a request to get service from geoserver

```
var sourceVector = new ol.source.Vector({
                // The service returns a GML and also allows return 500 polygons
                format:new ol.format.GML2({}),
                url:'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/siap/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=siap:ppb_curp&maxFeatures=500',
                loader: function (extent, resolution, projection) {
                        //var url = wfsBaseUrl;
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/siap/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=siap:ppb_curp&maxFeatures=500',
                            dataType: "xml",
                            success: function(response) {
                                console.log(sourceVector.getProjection());
                                var gml2format =new ol.format.GML2();
                                sourceVector.addFeatures(gml2format.readFeatures(response,
                                {
                                  featureProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
                                  dataProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
                                }
                                ));
                                console.log(gml2format.readFeatures(response));
                                map.getView().fit(sourceVector.getExtent(), map.getSize());

                                console.log(sourceVector.getExtent());
                            },
                            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                alert("The request has failed: " + textStatus);
                            }
                        });
                    }
            });
        //Vector to add styles to the polygon
        var layerVector = new ol.layer.Vector({
                name:'test',
                source: sourceVector,
                style: new ol.style.Style({
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1.0)',
                        width: 2
                    })
                })
            });
        map.addLayer(layerVector);
```

and all good but the polygons shows them to me by the avid attached image.

The polygons must show them in the area of ​​Mexico, I need some conversion? Any suggestion will help me a lot

[image]

Comment: How did you verify your featureProjection: 'EPSG:4326' and dataProjection: 'EPSG:3857' are accurate?

Comment: The view projection is not EPSG:4326 so `featureProjection: 'EPSG:4326'` is wrong.

Comment: It would be useful if you included an example of what is being logged by `console.log(gml2format.readFeatures(response));` which should be the features with their original data projection coordinates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a case of reversed X/Y coordinates which can happen in some WFS. It depends on how the WFS was configured. If you have control of the WFS, then you could set it to reverse the X/Y coordinates.

Alternatively, try adding the following line to your code:

```
gml2format.xy = false;
```

somewhere after you declare the `gml2format` variable.

I'm not a javascript or OpenLayers user, so I don't know for sure if this will work. I did, however, read a similar issue on [OpenLayers WFS flip coordinates](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/30602/7424).

Comment: The axis order is defined by the WFS/GML standards in use - either ask for 1.1.0 or make the client smarter

Comment: The xy property only applies to OpenLayers 2, it is not available in later versions

Comment: Also it is not an axis problem.  The features are at about 25E 72S but 72W 25N is not in Mexico.

Comment: I managed to solve it thanks to your comment  on the server they had it configured as EPSG: 900913 I changed it to EPSG: 4326  and @Ian Turton  
you are right change the version of WFS to WFS&version=1.1.0 finally the property xy I could not apply it since I am in version 3.7.0 of openlayers as i mention Mike

Answer (score 0):

Then I write the answer in case someone has the same problem

1.-Check that everything is well configured on the geoserver server

2.-modify this part

```
sourceVector.addFeatures(gml2format.readFeatures(response,
                            {
                              featureProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
                              dataProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
                            }
                            ));
```

by

```
sourceVector.addFeatures(gml2format.readFeatures(response,{}));
```

3.-finally change the version of WFS to WFS & version = 1.1.0

this is the final code

```
var sourceVector = new ol.source.Vector({
                // The service returns a GML and also allows filtering by an id
                format:new ol.format.GML2({

                }),
                url:'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/siap/ows?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=siap:ppb_curp&CQL_FILTER=curp=%27POPS63071XXXXXXXXX%27&outputFormat=text%2Fxml%3B+subtype%3Dgml%2F2.1.2',
                loader: function (extent, resolution, projection) {
                        //var url = wfsBaseUrl;
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/siap/ows?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=siap:ppb_curp&CQL_FILTER=curp=%27POPS63071XXXXXXXXX%27&outputFormat=text%2Fxml%3B+subtype%3Dgml%2F2.1.2',
                            dataType: "xml",
                            success: function(response) {
                                console.log(sourceVector.getProjection());
                                var gml2format =new ol.format.GML2({

                                });
                                //var lonlat = ol.proj.transform()
                                // gml2format.srsName = "EPSG:4326";
                                console.log(gml2format)

                                sourceVector.addFeatures(gml2format.readFeatures(response,{}));

                               // console.log(gml2format.readFeatures(response)[0].getGeometry().getCoordinates());
                              //  console.log(ol.proj.transform(gml2format.readFeatures(response)[0].getGeometry().getCoordinates()[0][0][0],'EPSG:4326','EPSG:3857'));
                                map.getView().fit(sourceVector.getExtent(), map.getSize());

                                console.log(sourceVector.getExtent());
                            },
                            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                alert("The request has failed: " + textStatus);
                            }
                        });
                    }

            });
        //Vector to add styles to the polygon
        var layerVector = new ol.layer.Vector({
                name:'test',
                source: sourceVector,
                style: new ol.style.Style({
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: 'rgba(240, 52, 52, 1)',
                    width: 2
                }),
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: 'rgba(240, 52, 52, 1)'
                })
                })
            });
        map.addLayer(layerVector);
```